# Unable to add note in Quix notebook

Tags: sql, linux, docker, presto

In the quix UI, I am unable to add a new note for writing scripts in notebook. I have used the docker-compose file to create containers for quix frontend and backend UI. Using the ip-address and port, I can access the UI for quix notebook manager. Below are the screenshots for the same.

I am unable to add new note using the "ADD NOTE" button

[image]

This is the .env file for quix

```
MODULES=presto


MODULES_PRESTO_ENGINE=presto
MODULES_PRESTO_API=http://presto:8080/v1
MODULES_PRESTO_CATALOG=system
MODULES_PRESTO_SCHEMA=runtime
MODULES_PRESTO_SOURCE=quix
MODULES_PRESTO_DB_EMPTY_TIMEOUT=60000
MODULES_PRESTO_DB_REQUEST_TIMEOUT=10000
MODULES_PRESTO_HTTP_HEADERS_PREFIX=X-PRESTO-

#MODULES_ATHENA_ENGINE=athena
#MODULES_ATHENA_OUTPUT=s3://some-bucket-id/
#MODULES_ATHENA_REGION=us-east-1
#MODULES_ATHENA_DATABASE=default
#MODULES_ATHENA_DB_EMPTY_TIMEOUT=60000
#MODULES_ATHENA_DB_REQUEST_TIMEOUT=10000

#MODULES_PROD_ENGINE=jdbc
#MODULES_PROD_DRIVER=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#MODULES_PROD_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:2222/aschema
#MODULES_PROD_USER=user
#MODULES_PROD_PASS=pass
#MODULES_PROD_SYNTAX=mysql

#MODULES_BQ_ENGINE=bigquery
#MODULES_BQ_SYNTAX=ansi_sql
#MODULES_BQ_CREDENTIALS_BASE64= BASE64 of credentials.json

#fake or google
AUTH_TYPE=fake
AUTH_USER=dummy-user
AUTH_COOKIE=
AUTH_SECRET=
#COOKIE_MAX_AGE=30
DB_NAME=quix
DB_USER=
DB_PASS=
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=
#BACKEND_INTERNAL_URL=
#BACKEND_PUBLIC_URL=
GOOGLE_SSO_CLIENT_ID=
GOOGLE_SSO_SECRET=
```

Below is the docker-compose file for building image and creating containers

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./quix-backend/
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - presto
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - MODULES
      - AUTH_COOKIE
      - AUTH_SECRET
      - AUTH_TYPE
  frontend:
    build: ./quix-frontend/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DB_NAME
      - DB_USER
      - DB_PASS
      - DB_HOST
      - DB_PORT
      - BACKEND_INTERNAL_URL
      - BACKEND_PUBLIC_URL
      - GOOGLE_SSO_CLIENT_ID
      - GOOGLE_SSO_SECRET
      - AUTH_COOKIE
      - AUTH_SECRET
      - AUTH_TYPE
      - APPMETRICS_PORT
      - ENABLE_APPMETRICS
      - MODULES
  db:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "quix"
    volumes:
      - "db_volume:/var/lib/mysql"
  presto:
    image: "starburstdata/presto:340-e"
    ports:
      - "8181:8080"
  postgres:
    image: "aa8y/postgres-dataset:dellstore"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  db_volume:
```

I want to add a new note in order to execute multiple scripts in a single notebook of quix.